# Ruby On rails project without tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know it is not recommended but is there a way to generate/modify an existing project so it doesn't create test files when using generators such as rails generate controller NAME?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
ruby script/generate controller Account --no-test-framework
```

Check out the [API](http://www.daokaous.com/rails3.0.0_doc/classes/Rails/Generators/Base.html).